# HttpURLConection - JSON Response isn't Complete

Tags: java, android, json, post, payload

I am trying to send a request to the [Grooveshark API](http://developers.grooveshark.com/tuts/public_api) using POST Payload and their requested methods, and I have found a problem. Allow me to show you my code first.

```
public void getResponse() throws Exception
{
    if(service.equals("Grooveshark")) link += getHmacMD5(privateGroovesharkKey, jsonInfo.toString());

    if(requestedMethod.equals("GET")) infoURL = new URL(link+arguments);
    else infoURL = new URL(link);

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) infoURL.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod(requestedMethod);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);

if(service.equals("Grooveshark"))
{
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
        OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
        output.write(jsonInfo.toString().getBytes());
}
else if(requestedMethod.equals("POST") || requestedMethod.equals("PUT"))
{
    OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
        output.write(arguments.getBytes());
}

    connection.connect();

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
        sb.append(line).append('\n');

    setJsonResult(sb.toString());

    System.out.println(jsonResult);

    jsonFinal = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

    connection.disconnect();
}
```

I have got that code up here in my project, and I can successfully send requested to any API Webservice that uses JSON in their responses. Now there's only a problem: In Android, it does not give me the ***WHOLE*** answer. I've tried running the code on a separate Java (no Android) project, and I get the following [output](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5348514/output.txt). Although, if I run it on Android, the Log shows me the following:

{"header":{"hostname":"RHL073"},"result":{"songs":[{"SongID":5443351,"SongName":"??????\u00b7???? (FINAL FANTASY XII????)","ArtistID":713,"ArtistName":"Final Fantasy","AlbumID":898007,"AlbumName":"Final Fantasy XII Original Soundtrack","CoverArtFilename":"","Popularity":1214500005,"IsLowBitrateAvailable":tr

And it stops on that tr. Has it anything to do with the parsing of the file that I actually apply afterwards? I don't think it is, but just in case, here it is [This is how I call the search, JSONHandler being the object that contains the code provided above]:

```
public void performSearch() throws Exception
{
    JSONObject search = new JSONObject();
    search.put("method", method);

    JSONObject header = new JSONObject();
    header.put("wsKey", key);

    JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
    parameters.put("query", getSearchQuery());
    parameters.put("country", "Portugal");
    parameters.put("limit", limit);
    parameters.put("offset", "");

    search.put("header", header);
    search.put("parameters", parameters);

    JSONHandler jsonHandler = new JSONHandler(link, search, "Grooveshark", "POST", "");

    JSONObject finalResult = jsonHandler.getJsonFinal();

    JSONArray songs = finalResult.getJSONObject("result").getJSONArray("songs");

    ArrayList<Result> allResults = new ArrayList<Result>();

    for(int i = 0; i < songs.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject inner = (JSONObject) songs.get(i);
        String name = inner.getString("SongName");
        int ID = inner.getInt("SongID");
        String artist = inner.getString("ArtistName");
        Result res = new Result(name, artist, ID);
        res.setAlbumName(inner.getString("AlbumName"));

        boolean low = inner.getBoolean("IsLowBitrateAvailable");
        int bit = 0;

        if(low) bit = 1;
        else bit = 0;

        res.setIsLowBitRateAvailable(bit);
    }

    setResults(allResults);
}
```

As you can clearly see, I am using the json.org library. I really don't understand what's the problem here. Has anyone got any idea as to why?

Comment: For starters, your code is sending the result of `String#getBytes()` - consider using a character set the server has a sporting chance of accepting - e.g. call `getBytes("UTF-8")` and amend your content-types.